# I can't connect to the webserver

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress instance running locally on my mac with XAMPP.
It's working fine but when I want to install something I have to login with my ftp username and password.

I've tried to use my username and password which I use to logon to WordPress. Also I used my tried my database credentials. I really have no idea which other logon credentials I should have.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

FTP credentials do not refer to your login details, it refers to credentials for File Transfer Protocol, it is given to you when you purchase a web hosting service or setup one yourself on your machine.

An alternative to this would be to download the plugin or theme you want and paste it to your /{website folder}/wp-content/themes or /{website folder}/wp-content/plugins

Answer (score 0):

Try to

1. Right click to htdocs folder, choose Get info
2. Click the lock icon, type your **MacOS account password** to unlock below options.
3. Allow everyone **Read & Write** permission, the click the `cog` icon and choose **Apply to enclosed items...**, this should apply all r+w permission to sub-folders.
4. Done

[image]